# Difference between Thread.activeCount() and ThreadGroup.activeCount()

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the difference between `Thread.activeCount()` and  `ThreadGroup.activeCount()`?

The oracle java docs say that the both methods return estimated threads number in the group (including the subgroups). When I'm getting a listing the values are differrent. What is the difference betwen these two attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for both methods ([`ThreadGroup.activeCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#activeCount()), [`Thread.activeCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#activeCount())) states that:

> The value returned is only an estimate because the number of threads
>   may change dynamically while this method traverses internal data
>   structures, and might be affected by the presence of certain system
>   threads. **This method is intended primarily for debugging and
>   monitoring purposes.**

Thus, it is possible that you have got different values because for example number of active threads in some of the subgroups has changed between the calls.

Comment: The difference is extremely big. For example, Thread.activeCount() is 32, but the ThreadGroup.activeCount is 5000.

Comment: `protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         PrintWriter PW = response.getWriter();
  Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
  Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++) {
PW.println(threadArray[i].getName()+"\t"+threadArray[i].getThreadGroup().getName()+"\t"+threadArray[i].getThreadGroup().activeCount()+"\t"+threadArray[i].getState().toString()+"\t"+active.toString());

  }
           } 
 }`

Comment: To be more clear. I'm putting the activeCount values in one String line

`threadArray[i].getName()+"\t"+threadArray[i].getThreadGroup().getName()+"\t"+threadArray[i].getThreadGroup().activeCount()+"\t"+threadArray[i].getState().toString()+"\t"+active.toString()`

So, there is no big time difference between these two method calls.

Comment: I still think this may be related to have your Servlet is implemented, although the difference in what both of these methods return is indeed large. But there may be some time difference difference between those calls, even though in the source code both calls are in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in the returned values:

**[activeCount](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#activeCount())**

> public int activeCount()
>
> Returns an estimate of the number of active threads in this thread group and its subgroups. Recursively iterates over all subgroups in this thread group.
>
> The value returned is only an estimate because the number of threads may change dynamically while this method traverses internal data structures, and might be affected by the presence of certain system threads. This method is intended primarily for debugging and monitoring purposes.
>
> **Returns:**
> **An estimate of the number of active threads in this thread group and in any other thread group that has this thread group as an ancestor.**

**[activeGroupCount](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#activeGroupCount())**

> public int activeGroupCount()
>
> Returns an estimate of the number of active groups in this thread group and its subgroups. Recursively iterates over all subgroups in this thread group.
>
> The value returned is only an estimate because the number of thread groups may change dynamically while this method traverses internal data structures. This method is intended primarily for debugging and monitoring purposes.
>
> **Returns:**
> **The number of active thread groups with this thread group as an ancestor**